# Node crypto sha256 not working with whitespace

Tags: node.js, cryptography, content-security-policy, jsdom

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

When using

```
var checkSum = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(scriptInnerHTML, "utf-8").digest("base64")
```

To generate the sha256 for this script tag:

```
<script>

    console.warn("works");
    var some code ... 
</script>
```

And using it inside a Content-Security-Policy like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'sha256-8O+YTKIDgMhMvSanTZx1Om5XY2ERB+kIxN8AcO2r6Ok='">
```

Things works as it should, but however this one, identical except without the warning-log, doesn't work. Notice the couple of new-lines and a tab before the code.

```
<script>


    var some code ... 
</script>
```

It seems as Node interprets tabs (or rather newlines+tab) differently if there is text afterwards. Weird!

Tested both in Safari and Chrome so it should not be a browser issue.

*Updates*: 
I of-course re-generate the hash for each input.

Examples:

(The script tag is at the bottom)

Working hash ('sha256-5++3ItSu+9maCZiuuXH60RG7EugmibMmhxhwpsynAn0='): http://aggressive.se/test/works.html

Not working hash ('sha256-hIRDHGUSaEmjNiVhNabY+8l4GNQdj/PXD4XHA21gdRM='): http://aggressive.se/test/fail.html

***SOLVED:***
The problem was due to the serialize() function in JSDom which I use to generate the HTML in node. Calling dom.serialize() after calculating the hash, it removed one unnecessary tab which changed the source (in a hard to notice way).

But just so you know, the problem was not due to node nor the crypto module. (Hope someone has use for this)

Comment: could you post somewhere the non-working example? it's most likely because some extraneous white-space character, but it's hard to detect this in the post here... Alternatively, you might use a [nonce](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/#if_you_absolutely_must_use_it) instead of the hash.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. You remove a warning log line from the hash input and then you are surprised it doesn't compare with the hash that included the warning line? Or am I seeing ghosts?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes sorry - bad writing. The hash function is re-run for each input.

Comment: @ewcz Updated with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you obtained the `scriptInnerHTML` variable, but if I access the `innerHTML` property of the script of interest in the `fail.html` example, I get this hexdump:

```
00000000  0a 0a 0a 09 76 61 72 20  6c 61 79 6f 75 74 20 3d  |....var layout =|
00000010  20 6e 65 77 20 41 67 67  72 65 73 73 69 76 65 4c  | new AggressiveL|
00000020  61 79 6f 75 74 28 29 3b  0a 09 41 67 67 72 65 73  |ayout();..Aggres|
00000030  73 69 76 65 4c 61 79 6f  75 74 2e 70 72 6f 74 6f  |siveLayout.proto|
00000040  74 79 70 65 2e 73 65 74  75 70 46 75 6e 63 74 69  |type.setupFuncti|
00000050  6f 6e 20 3d 20 66 75 6e  63 74 69 6f 6e 28 29 0a  |on = function().|
00000060  09 7b 0a 09 09 76 61 72  20 65 6c 65 6d 65 6e 74  |.{...var element|
00000070  20 3d 20 64 6f 63 75 6d  65 6e 74 2e 63 72 65 61  | = document.crea|
00000080  74 65 45 6c 65 6d 65 6e  74 28 22 64 69 76 22 29  |teElement("div")|
00000090  3b 0a 09 09 65 6c 65 6d  65 6e 74 2e 69 6e 6e 65  |;...element.inne|
000000a0  72 48 54 4d 4c 20 3d 20  22 49 74 20 77 6f 72 6b  |rHTML = "It work|
000000b0  73 22 3b 0a 09 09 74 68  69 73 2e 65 6c 65 6d 65  |s";...this.eleme|
000000c0  6e 74 73 2e 72 6f 6f 74  45 6c 65 6d 65 6e 74 2e  |nts.rootElement.|
000000d0  61 70 70 65 6e 64 43 68  69 6c 64 28 65 6c 65 6d  |appendChild(elem|
000000e0  65 6e 74 29 0a 09 7d 0a                           |ent)..}.|
```

the corresponding hash of which is `bR9Os+NBLWNZ3/wFVRhBilP05u9OeSj0ABRo+T8QF+g=`. If I use this hash in the html file, it seems to work...

An example with `JSDOM`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

const dom = new JSDOM(fs.readFileSync('./fail.html'));
const data = dom.window.document.querySelector('head > script:last-child').innerHTML;

console.log(crypto.createHash('sha256').update(data, 'utf-8').digest('base64'));
//bR9Os+NBLWNZ3/wFVRhBilP05u9OeSj0ABRo+T8QF+g=
```

Comment: Thanks! I use JSDom to get the innerHTML, but to be extra sure I also set the innerHTML with the string used to generate the hash. But perhaps JSDom is doing  magical converts with whitespaces that creates this bug...

Comment: @Olof_t I included an example with `JSDom`, it seems to give the correct hash. For the selector, I used `head > script:last-child`, i.e., to get the last `script` element in the `head`

Comment: The problem was when calling dom.serialize(), it removed one unnecessary tab, which changed the source - and thus mismatching hashes. Anyhow: two hundred thank-yous for helping me with this!